# JS Calculations from one nodeList to another

Tags: javascript

Quite new to JS but have a little programming knowledge. Trying to do something probably a bit beyond my experience, but it's part of a project I'm working on, and I'm hoping to get this part of it done.

I basically want to iterate through one nodeList, run calculations on those items and put them in another nodeList.

```html
<span id ="item1">20</span><span id = "item2">0</span>
<span id ="item1">15</span><span id = "item2">0</span>
<span id ="item1">10</span><span id = "item2">0</span>
```

I want to multiply item1 by 1000 and place that figure in the item2.

```html
<span id ="item1">20</span><span id = "item2">20000</span>
<span id ="item1">15</span><span id = "item2">15000</span>
<span id ="item1">10</span><span id = "item2">10000</span>
```

I appreciate that JS will be rendering the code above, but I hope that this makes what I want a bit clearer.

I know that I need to select everything with querySelectAll:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('#item1');
```

I've managed to do this for a single item with querySelector, but I think I may have bitten off more than I can chew with a nodeList! I know that I need to iterate through this data with either a for loop or forEach, but JS seems to have quite a lot of different methods for looping through data, and the nodeList factor adds an extra layer of complexity!

Thanks in advance for your help/hints!

Edit:

Responding to the comments below so the html isn't exactly like that, I just thought it might be simpler to do this in html. It's actually a Flask app, so the code is in a Jinja2 template, looping through items from a database.

```
{% for x in y.items %}
...
<div class="card-footer"><span id ="item">{{ item.id }}</span><span id = "itemAnother"></span>*calculatedNumberHere*</div>
...
{% endfor %}
```

EDIT:

```
<div class="card-footer"><span class="item">{{ item.id }}</span><span class="itemAnother"></span>*calculatedNumberHere*</div>
```

Was the updated Jinja2 code, and Diwakar's answer in JS was used verbatim and it worked.

Comment: `id` attributes must be unique

Comment: You've to rething the logic, multiple same ids is invalid HTML, use classes instead.

Comment: Your HTML structure is making things difficult, beyond having the same id for multiple elements. 1 - you'd have to extract just the text you want from the parent element without including anything from the child element, 2 - your span-inside-span structure makes everything render to look like just one long number

Comment: folks thanks for these comments, I clearly have a bit more work to do with my html. Diwakar's answer below was the answer and I got this running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `class` instead of `id`

```js
const items1List = document.querySelectorAll('.item1')
const items2List = document.querySelectorAll('.item2')
items1List.forEach((item, index)=>{
  const num = Number.parseInt(item.innerText)
  if(!Number.isNaN()){
  items2List[index].innerText = num * 1000
}
})
```

```html
<span class='item1'>10</span>
<span class='item2'></span>

<span class='item1'>12</span>
<span class='item2'></span>

<span class='item1'>32</span>
<span class='item2'></span>
```

Comment: Thanks dude, this worked! I clearly have a bit of study to do here, but this really helps to get me moving forward with my project!